# Let $p_3(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into parts that are not multiples of 3. What is the generating function for the sequence $\{p_3(n)\}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I believe that in order to solve this Eulers theorem must be used, where the generating function $P(x)$ of $(p(n))_{n\geq0}$ is
$$P(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^k}$$
I am not sure, however, how to remove all factors that are multiples of 3. How can this be solved? Thanks.

Comment: See also [OEIS sequence A000726](https://oeis.org/A000726)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} p_{3}(n) x^{n} = (1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots)(1+x^{2}+x^{4}+\cdots)(1+x^{4}+x^{8}+\cdots)\cdots = \prod_{3\nmid k}\frac{1}{1-x^{k}} = \frac{\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-x^{k}}}{\prod_{3|k}\frac{1}{1-x^{k}}} = \frac{P(x)}{P(x^{3})}
$$

Comment: That's quite cool! Also gives: $$\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\frac{1-(x^2)^3}{1-x^2}\frac{1-(x^3)^3}{1-x^3}\cdots=(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3+x^6)\cdots .$$ Nice!

Comment: @N.Shales That's quite interesting, since this identity shows that $p_{3}(n)$ is same as the number of partitions of $n$ where each number occurs at most twice. Also, this can be generalized for $p_{m}(n)$.

Comment: I know, cool, right? I'm not sure how useful this is (probably not very) but each factor is of the kind $1+u+u^2$ with $u=x,x^2,x^3\ldots$ which can be written $(1+ue^{i\pi/3})(1+ue^{-i\pi/3})$. I was just exploring ideas really.